# Rails 3: Uninitialized constant in Controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, datatables

I am following ryan bate's video: http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables?view=comments,
to learn how to connect the jquery datatables plugin to the server side to speed up the page load time. I am using Rails 3.

I am getting this weird error and I'm not sure what it means:

```
"NameError (uninitialized constant ReportsController::ReportsDatatable):
 app/controllers/reports_controller.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in index'
 app/controllers/reports_controller.rb:18:in `index'"
```

It's especially strange because sometimes I get the error and other times I do not. I usually occurs when the table first loads, or (when the page does load) when I try to go to the next page..

Inside my reports controller:

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: ReportsDatatable.new(view_context) }
    end
  end
end
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: And I know it is not a routes issue, because the index action on the reports controller was working before I began adding datatables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use :: to go to global namespace:

```
  format.json { render json: ::ReportsDatatable.new(view_context) }
```